# Final failure mode of Cosori electric pressure cooker when lid is left unlocked?

Tags: pressure-cooker, kitchen-safety

One reason I prefer an electronic pressure cooker to a regular stove for safety  is that it won't start without setting the count-down timer to turn it back off.  (I am forgetful, and have 3 times fallen asleep with something on the stove.)

Well, unfortunately, my new Cosori electronic pressure cooker's count-down timer does not start until pressure is reached, but pressure will never be reached if you forget to twist the pressure lid to lock in the pressure.  The damn thing doesn't warn you by beeping or refusing to start or anything if you forget to twist the lid to lock.

Have any Cosori users here ever forgotten to seal the lid and observed in practice what the final failure mode is after all the water boils off?

Comment: If the manufacturer's customer support can't answer a legit safety question like that, they are not the kind of maker I would want to buy potentially dangerous equipment from again. I would, though, bet that the final safety mechanism is found in the manual, in a statement of "do not run it unattended". Do not rely on anecdotal evidence of exact behaviours of complex electronics - a device like that is likely software controlled internally, and software gets changed by makers without any change in appearance.